# Multiple DML statements on their own vs. being grouped in a single WITH statement

Tags: postgresql

Are there any reasons to prefer

```sql
BEGIN;
UPDATE [...];
INSERT [...];
DELETE [...];
COMMIT;
```

over

```sql
WITH
u AS (UPDATE [...]),
i AS (INSERT [...]),
DELETE [...])
```

and vice versa?

Comment: the second might need more memory.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How so? The statements don't return anything. What would be stored in memory then?

Comment: The enqueueing of AFTER triggers, and maybe referential integrity checks.

Comment: @jjanes Thanks! So it seems that a `WITH` query can be used to simulated deferred triggers in some limited cases, nice.